# Usando Testes de Instrumentação para validar Layout no Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mockito

Gente,

Antes de fazer fazer a minha pergunta, abaixo está um exemplo de código de instrumentação (incompleto propositalmente) no Android:

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import br.com.topoil.account.LoginActivity
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    fun loadActivity() {

        val i = Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity::class.java)

        var scenario = launch<LoginActivity>(i)
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
    }
}
```

Supondo que vc coloque um breakpoint exatamente nesta linha:

```
scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
```

O comportamento desse teste será o seguinte: A LoginActivity vai aparecer belezinha no Android! E era isso exatamente que eu queria, validar o layout. Para isso o teste não pode "encerrar" o ciclo de vida, entrar no @After etc.

É evidente que quebra um galho e ajuda bastante para ver de verdade como a Activity ficará no estado inicial (nesse exemplo) logo depois de escrever o código da Activity e testar em um aparelho real.

Como o teste de instrumentação tem um ciclo de vida definido: Before, Test e After, se obviamente não colocar o breakpoint exatamente ali e depurar, a Activity aparece e some imediatamente (que é exatamente isso que acontece - e está certo).

Então a pergunta é: Existe uma forma de testar os layouts mais eficientemente no Android Studio e rodar uma Activity "mockada" para ela entrar em um estado inicial e não sumir, sem a necessidade de escrever um teste de instrumentação?

Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Mateus, beleza?

Respondendo sua pergunta, tem sim! E é mais ou menos o que você imaginou.

As duas formas mais conhecidas são:

- **[ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario)**;
- **[ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule)**;

A descrição da ActivityScenarioRule aparentemente é a que mais se encaixa pra você:

> ActivityScenarioRule launches a given activity before the test starts and closes after the test.

A doc está bem completa e é facinho de implementar.

Aah, e você também pode usar o **[Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista)**, que é um wrapper do espresso. Assim você vai conseguir fazer várias validações com apenas algumas funcs.


Espero ter ajudado ;) Abraços.

**[Neste link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing)** você pode ver a implementação do activity scenario rule.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTestSuite {

        @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MyActivity>()
    
        @Test fun testEvent() {
            val scenario = activityScenarioRule.scenario
            onView(withId(R.id.finish_button)).perform(click())
        }
    }
```

Comment: obrigado!!! :-D Vou olhar com calma! De qualquer maneira, o jeito "macarrônico" citado acima me ajudou por algumas vezes kakakakak. Lógico, não é o ideal, mas rapaz eu procurei isso hein! Vou dar uma olhada no Barista também! :-D Valeu pela dica meu amigo! ótima semana para vc!

Comment: Que isso, eu que agradeço.
Tem esse tutorial bem legal nas docs, ensinando a implementar:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing